# make one div scrollable till end if another overlaps (basically change height of the div)

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-position

In the image the cart items are scrollable but if i open the promotion accordian it overlaps the middle contents the cart items are still scrollable but end items get hidden behind the accordian contents

[image]

I have accordian position as fixed and the middle cart body is absolute.

I want to make cart items to be viewed even after opening accordian and after closing as well.

https://int.balibodyco.com/ have the same. I want something like this

Comment: https://int.balibodyco.com/ URL not working

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please take a tour of the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you unless you provide enough code to replicate your problem - see [mcve]

Comment: @sumeshsn1 https://int.balibodyco.com/ hope you can open it now

Comment: @DarshanaSonawane can you share your code? it's very difficult to guess

Comment: @sumeshsn1 sure i will attach the code

Comment: can you share your email id the code is quite long to share here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `overflow: scroll;` to the style of your div.

Comment: Thank you for your response i have already added overflow scroll for this.

Comment: I will tell you section wise i think the issue is with height or position - 1) header - fixed position 2) Cart items body - absolute position 3)accordion - fixed position and auto scroll 4)total and checkout buttons fixed at bottom. What can be the issue

Comment: Also z-index can be issue as elements are overlapping